# java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't create a file because of some error in filename , facing this error in only some devices ex:android 4.1.2

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

```
File external = getExternalFilesDir(null);

//fd is stringbuffer whose value is "year1:semester:2"

File file = new File(external,""+fd.toString()+".txt"); // <----error

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(store.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This is the exception generated:

```
W/System.err(29169): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.ddu/files/Year:1Semester:2.txt: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: @Pieter please be more careful when editing, as you introduced additional whitespace not in the original *within* the path name displayed in the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a file which has a colon (**:**) in its name. Replace the colon with something else.

Comment: this code is working in my device...its just not working in some devices

Comment: yes..thank you :) ...it worked...but this is really confusing why was the above code running successfully in some devices and giving exceptions in others?

Comment: See the problem is with the device. Certain devices/OS reject some characters as valid file names. For example in Windows you cannot have a file with : or / or > or < in the name. This is platform specific. Some platform may not consider these invalid. I hope you understood. Please accept as the answer. :)